# Swift performance question: Load deserialized objects from database in memory or perform serialize/deserialize on update of db entry

Tags: ios, json, swift, serialization

I am using a sqlite database to store the user created contents of the app. As the user has the option to add and edit an unlimited amount of different objects like testfields or imageviews, I use serialized JSON to store as a string in the sqlite database.

My VC hierarchy looks simplified a bit like this:

```
ViewController
|- ScrollView
   |- UIView 1 - representing one content item
      |- TextField - content element 1
      |- TextField - content element 2
      |- TextField ...
      |- ImageView ...
      |- ImageView ...
      |- potential other views
      |- ...
   |- UIView 2 ...
```

Now the question is, what is the most performant pattern to keep track and update the changes of those objects (memory and speed wise). I came up with 2 potential patterns:

1. Every `TextField`, `ImageView` etc. created inside one of the content item UIView is a specific subclass which gets the deserialized JSON content item holding all the content elements as a property. On the respective edit function, it updates the deserialized JSON object, serializes it again and updates the database entry. The problem is: All the other content element objects need to get the updated deserialized JSON as well, and something like a `NotificationCenter` message would be needed to send the updated object. Also with a lot of objects they all would hold the whole deserialized JSON object in memory.
2. Every `TextField`, `ImageView` etc. just holds a reference to the content item ID, and on the update of the element, the content element would get the content item with the respective ID from the sqlite db, deserialize it, update it, serialize it again and update the db entry. The potential problem: Would the whole process of each `select query -> deserialize -> update object -> serialize -> update query` maybe take too long (e.g. lag for the UI)?

Is there maybe a better pattern for this?